# Passing "on_start data" to MyScreen and MyImage requires Screen name in ScreenManager

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am using Kivy library to create an app using mainly Python code. I am newbie in Python and Kivy. Here some snippets of my code.

I was trying to pass an image defined "on_start" to my NavButton. @ikolim helped me out to identify the issue. You can see my comments below.

**Widget**

```
class NavButton(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NavButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 1
        frame = FloatLayout(id = "frame")
        grid1 = MyGrid(
            rows = 1,
            cols = 5,
            pos_hint = {"top":1, "left": 1},
            size_hint = [1, .2]                         )
        grid1.set_background(0.95,0.95,0.95,1)

        grid1.add_widget(MyButton(
            source = "img/settings.png",
            size_hint = [0.2,0.2]                       ))
        grid1.add_widget(MyButton(
            source = "img/arrow-left.png"               ))
        city_icon = Image(
            source="img/image1.png",
            id="city_icon",
            size_hint=[0.8, 0.8])

        self.ids.cityicon = city_icon
        grid1.add_widget(city_icon)
        grid1.add_widget(MyButton(
            source = "img/arrow-right.png"              ))
        grid1.add_widget(MyButton(
            source = "img/globe.png",
            size_hint = [0.2,0.2]                       ))
        frame.add_widget(grid1)
        self.add_widget(frame)
```

#### Screens

```
class Homescreen(Screen):

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Homescreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            frame = FloatLayout(id = "frame")
            grid1 = NavButton()
            frame.add_widget(grid1)

        ...
```

#### Screen Manager

Here is where I was messing up! Apparently you have to define the name of your homescreen (i.e.`homescreen = Homescreen(name="home_screen")`) otherwise it does not update the image of the NavButton when you start the application. I am not sure why but I just what to highlight this for future coders.

```
 class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        homescreen = Homescreen()
        self.add_widget(homescreen)
        self.ids.screenmanager =  self

    def change_screen(self, name):
         self.current = name
```

#### Builder

```
GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class Main(App):

    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def on_start(self):

        self.mynewimage = "image2"
        homescreen = self.root.get_screen("home_screen")
        homescreen.ids.navbutton.ids.cityicon.source = f"img/{self.mynewimage}.png"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

Again, @ikolim thanks for your support.

Comment: Is it enough for you to change the variable over a setter method or do you want to "change" this picture in the constructor? Because if you want the variable in the constructor just make the variable my_city global... There might be a better way but I think this is the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 2

The following enhancements are required to solve the problem.

### class NavButton()

1. Replace `self.ids.cityicon = "cityicon"`
   with `self.ids.cityicon = city_icon`
2. Delete `self.bind(on_start=self.update_image)` and method `update_image()`

### Method `on_start()`

1. Replace `homescreen =
   Main.get_running_app().root.get_screen("home_screen")` with
   `homescreen = self.root.get_screen("home_screen")`
2. Replace
       `frame.children[3].children[0].children[0].children[2].source` with
       `homescreen.ids.navbutton.ids.cityicon.source`
3. Remove lines (`frame = homescreen.children[0]`, `navbutton =
   frame.children[3]`, and `print(...)`)

### Snippets - py file

```
class NavButton(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NavButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ...
        city_icon = Image(
            source="img/settings.png",
            id="city_icon",
            size_hint=[0.8, 0.8])

        self.ids.cityicon = city_icon
        ...


class Main(App):

    ...

    def on_start(self):
        self.my_city = "it-Rome"
        homescreen = self.root.get_screen("home_screen")
        homescreen.ids.navbutton.ids.cityicon.source = f"img/{self.my_city}.png"
    ...
```

### Example - main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle


class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


### Components

class NavButton(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NavButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 1
        frame = FloatLayout(id="frame")
        grid1 = MyGrid(
            rows=1,
            cols=5,
            pos_hint={"top": 1, "left": 1},
            size_hint=[1, .2])
        grid1.set_background(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1)

        grid1.add_widget(MyButton(
            source="img/settings.png",
            size_hint=[0.2, 0.2]))
        grid1.add_widget(MyButton(
            source="img/arrow-left.png"))
        city_icon = Image(
            source="img/settings.png",
            id="city_icon",
            size_hint=[0.8, 0.8])

        self.ids.cityicon = city_icon

        grid1.add_widget(city_icon)
        grid1.add_widget(MyButton(
            source="img/arrow-right.png"))
        grid1.add_widget(MyButton(
            source="img/globe.png",
            size_hint=[0.2, 0.2]))
        frame.add_widget(grid1)
        self.add_widget(frame)


### Grids

class MyGrid(GridLayout):

    def set_background(self, r, b, g, o):
        self.canvas.before.clear()
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(r, g, b, o)
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect,
                  size=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size


### Screens

class Homescreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Homescreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        frame = FloatLayout(id="frame")
        grid1 = NavButton()
        frame.add_widget(grid1)

        # This grid contains the number of zpots collected

        grid2 = MyGrid(
            cols=1,
            pos_hint={"top": 0.8, "left": 1},
            size_hint=[1, .2], )
        grid2.add_widget(Image(
            source="img/spot.png"))
        grid2.add_widget(Label(
            text="[color=3333ff]20/30[/color]",
            markup=True))
        grid2.set_background(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1)
        frame.add_widget(grid2)

        # This grid contains a scrollable list of nearby zpots

        grid3 = MyGrid(
            cols=1,
            pos_hint={"top": 0.6, "left": 1},
            size_hint=[1, .5])
        grid3.set_background(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1)
        frame.add_widget(grid3)

        # This grid contains a the map of nearby zpots

        grid4 = MyGrid(
            cols=1,
            pos_hint={"top": 0.1, "left": 1},
            size_hint=[1, .1])
        grid4.set_background(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1)
        frame.add_widget(grid4)
        self.ids.navbutton = grid1
        self.add_widget(frame)


class Newscreen(Screen):
    pass


class Settingscreen(Screen):
    pass


### ScreenManager

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        homescreen = Homescreen(name='home_screen')
        self.add_widget(homescreen)
        self.ids.screenmanager = self

    def change_screen(self, name):
        self.current = name


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

    def on_start(self):
        self.my_city = "it-Rome"
        homescreen = self.root.get_screen("home_screen")

        print(f"\non_start-Before change: img={homescreen.ids.navbutton.ids.cityicon.source}")
        homescreen.ids.navbutton.ids.cityicon.source = f"img/{self.my_city}.png"
        print(f"\non_start-After change: img={homescreen.ids.navbutton.ids.cityicon.source}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### Output

[image: App started]

## Solution 1

- Use [`App.get_running_app()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app) function to get an instance of your application
- Add `self` in-front of `my_city`

### Snippets - py file

```
class NavButton(GridLayout):

    def get(self):
        ...
        city_icon = Image(
                source = "img/" + App.get_running_app().my_city,
                size_hint = [0.8,0.8]                       )

...
class Main(App):

    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def on_start(self):
        # get data from DB
        self.my_city = "it-Rome"
```

Comment: not working... maybe I did something wrong. Still looking for a workaround... maybe with a bind function... not sure how to use it, though...

Comment: Did you get any error(s)? Please share your updated app in Google Drive or GitHub

Comment: Is the image, "it-Rome" from the database and what is the data type, BLOB?

Comment: Please refer to updated post for solution 2 details.

Comment: Hi @ikolim, I updated the code but no change. I am glad to see it works on your terminal. Is it possible the problem is somewhere else? Here the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084897/11748460

Comment: Please refer to updated post with `main.py`.  Copy, paste, and run my example, main.py. The `f"img/{self.my_city}.png"` is Python 3's the [fancier output formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

Comment: ok! @ikolim! thanks for your support. I compared my code with yours. I literally copied and paste my code on top of your to identify what was not working. The critical difference is that you added the name to your homescreen`homescreen = Homescreen(name = "home_screen")` while I did not. If I apply the same change in my code, it works... not sure what is the reason behind... do you have any idea?